# Antlr Array Help

Tags: antlr

Hey ive started to use Antlr with java and i wanted to know how i can store some values directly into a 2d array and return this array? i cant find any tutorials on this at all, all help is apperciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's say you want to parse a flat text file containing numbers separated by spaces. You'd like to parse this into a 2d array of `int`'s where each line is a "row" in your array.

The ANTLR grammar for such a "language" could look like:

```
grammar Number;

parse
  :  line* EOF
  ;

line
  :  Number+ (LineBreak | EOF)
  ;

Number
  :  ('0'..'9')+
  ;

Space
  :  (' ' | '\t') {skip();}
  ;

LineBreak
  :  '\r'? '\n'
  |  '\r'
  ;
```

Now, you'd like to have the `parse` rule return an `List` of `List<Integer>` objects. Do that by adding a `returns [List<List<Integer>> numbers]` after your `parse` rule which can be initialized in an `@init{ ... }` block:

```
parse returns [List<List<Integer>> numbers]
@init {
  $numbers = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
}
  :  line* EOF
  ;
```

Your `line` rule looks a bit the same, only it returns a 1 dimensional list of numbers:

```
line returns [List<Integer> row]
@init {
  $row = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
  :  Number+ (LineBreak | EOF)
  ;
```

The next step is to fill the `List`s with the actual values that are being parsed. This can be done embedding the code `{$row.add(Integer.parseInt($Number.text));}` inside the `Number+` loop in your `line` rule:

```
line returns [List<Integer> row]
@init {
  $row = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
  :  (Number {$row.add(Integer.parseInt($Number.text));})+ (LineBreak | EOF)
  ;
```

And lastly, you'll want to add the `List`s being returned by your `line` rule to be actually added to your 2D `numbers` list from your `parse` rule:

```
parse returns [List<List<Integer>> numbers]
@init {
  $numbers = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
}
  :  (line {$numbers.add($line.row);})* EOF
  ;
```

Below is the final grammar:

```
grammar Number;

parse returns [List<List<Integer>> numbers]
@init {
  $numbers = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
}
  :  (line {$numbers.add($line.row);})* EOF
  ;

line returns [List<Integer> row]
@init {
  $row = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
  :  (Number {$row.add(Integer.parseInt($Number.text));})+ (LineBreak | EOF)
  ;

Number
  :  ('0'..'9')+
  ;

Space
  :  (' ' | '\t') {skip();}
  ;

LineBreak
  :  '\r'? '\n'
  |  '\r'
  ;
```

which can be tested with the following class:

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String source = 
                "1 2       \n" +
                "3 4 5 6 7 \n" +
                "      8   \n" +
                "9 10 11     ";
        ANTLRStringStream in = new ANTLRStringStream(source);
        NumberLexer lexer = new NumberLexer(in);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        NumberParser parser = new NumberParser(tokens);
        List<List<Integer>> numbers = parser.parse();
        System.out.println(numbers);
    }
}
```

Now generate a lexer and parser from the grammar:

```
java -cp antlr-3.2.jar org.antlr.Tool Number.g
```

compile all `.java` source files:

```
javac -cp antlr-3.2.jar *.java
```

and run the main class:

```
// On *nix
java -cp .:antlr-3.2.jar Main

// or Windows
java -cp .;antlr-3.2.jar Main
```

which produces the following output:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8], [9, 10, 11]]
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Here's some excerpts from a grammar I made that parses people's names and returns a `Name` object.  Should be enough to show you how it works.  Other objects such as arrays are done the same way.

In the grammar:

```
grammar PersonNames;

fullname returns [Name name]
@init {
    name = new Name();
}
  : (directory_style[name] | standard[name] | title_without_fname[name] |      family_style[name] | proper_initials[name]) EOF;

standard[Name name]
 : (title[name] ' ')* fname[name] ' ' (mname[name] ' ')* (nickname[name] ' ')? lname[name] (sep honorifics[name])*;

 fname[Name name] : (f=NAME | f=INITIAL)  { name.set(Name.Part.FIRST, toNameCase($f.text)); };
```

in your regular Java code

```
public static Name parseName(String str) throws RecognitionException {
    System.err.println("parsing `" + str + "`");
    CharStream stream = new ANTLRStringStream(str);
    PersonNamesLexer lexer = new PersonNamesLexer(stream);
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    PersonNamesParser parser = new PersonNamesParser(tokens);

    return parser.fullname();
}
```