# Using ANTLR 4 to parse file into an array?

Tags: java, antlr, grammar, antlr4

I'm very new to ANTLR and I am currently using the ANTLRWorks 2 plugin for Netbeans IDE 7.3 to visualize my grammar files for ANTLR 4.1.

What I am trying to do is parse a text file with line separated dollar values and return them all in a one-dimensional array of doubles "double[]."

For example say I have a file values.txt which contains:...

```
12.40
16.91
18.00
17.97
12.85
```

...I want to use the ANTLR generated **Parser.parseMethod(tokens)* to return an array. So the return value would be {12.4,16.91,18.00,17.85,12.85}

I attempted to adapt this method I found by a similar question answered here - [Antlr Array Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354758/antlr-array-help) -, and settle on working with a list, resulting in the following code:

```
grammar Values;

parse returns [List<Double> numbers]
@init {
  $numbers = new ArrayList<Double>();
}
  :  (line {$numbers.add($line.row);})* EOF
  ;

line returns [Double row]
@init {
  $row = new Double(0.0);
}
  :  (Number {$row = Double.parseDouble($Number.text);})+ (LineBreak | EOF)
  ;

fragment Digit : ('0'..'9')+ ;
Number : Digit '.' Digit ;
Space
  :  (' ' | '\t') -> channel(HIDDEN)
  ;

    LineBreak
  :  '\r'? '\n'
  |  '\r'
  ;
```

But once this grammar file is generated the parse() method returns a "ParseContext" object...

```
public final ParseContext parse() throws RecognitionException {...}
```

...which I do not know how to use.  And I do not know why *ParseContext* is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANTLR 4 generates a context class for every rule which is used to represent invocations of that rule in the final parse tree. The name is derived from the rule name, so rule `parse` is represented by `ParseContext` and rule `foo` is represented by `FooContext`. The `ParseContext` class produced by your grammar will provide you with access to several things, including the following items specific to your grammar.

- The `numbers` return value will be stored in the generated field `ParseContext.numbers`.
- The generated `line()` method will return a `List<LineContext>` containing the parse tree node for each invocation of the `line` rule from `parse`.
- The class will also contain supporting methods required for the ANTLR 4 listener and visitor functionality to work.